# Как в компоненте ListView выделить цветом "нажатый" пункт?

Tags: java, android

Есть

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvBase);
```

И обработчик "нажатий"

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        currentPos = position;
        }
});
```

Как выделить ("подсветить" или цветом) выбранный пункт?

Comment: вам нужна реакция на клик или "зафиксировать" нажатие, чтобы элемент, на который нажали, оставался выделенным?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо задать drawable типа:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_activated="true"
        android:drawable="@color/selectedColor"
        />
    <item
        android:drawable="@color/transparent"
        />
</selector>
```

И сделать на него ссылку в лейауте строки списка:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/rowLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/record_selector" <!-- смотрим сюда-->
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:clickable="false"
    >
 <!-- blah-blah-->
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Чего-то не получается :( Я правильно понимаю, надо создать record_selector.xml , а потом прописать <LinearLayout ... в list_Items в адаптере adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.list_items, list4lv);

Comment: Так не будет работать. Вам нужно делать собственный адаптер - подход, который я обрисовал работоспособен для кастомного адаптера.